# Windows installer seems to be failing. Cannot install windows updates

Tags: windows-7, updates

I am working on a Dell Inspiron 660 desktop with Intel core i3-2130 CPU @3.40GHz with Windows 7 Home Premium 32bit.

I was having issues installing a TurboTax update and it seemed to be a windows installer problem, however it succeeded on 4 out of 5 updates. I then tried to install windows updates and all 35 failed.

The TurboTax update gave me a Microsoft error code 1648 and I researched it and attempted every solution they gave such as `sfc /scannow`, and `chkdsk /r` none of them worked. Due to so many fails, I decided to do a completely fresh install of Windows and I now have 145 updates that are also failing.

Comment: Are you using some kind of Loader? Some of them brake updates.
Remamber to restart your computer few times - updated sometimes stuck without proper reboot.
Check event Viewer in Admin tools in Control Panel, there should be some kind of clue

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip it and upload the zip (Cloud hoster) and post a link here

Comment: I am not using a Loader, and as of right now the new install is stuck on the 64th update out of 145. This is what I received when I opened event viewer (keep in mind I just wiped and reloaded OS) MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly.    Name: Event Viewer      CLSID:FX:{b05566ad-fe9c-4363-be05-7a4cbb7cb510

Comment: clean install from clean install iso? saw few that ended with broken update. I would try with different iso (like msdnaa ones)

Comment: @MichałPółrolniczak  I converted your answer to a comment because it's more asking for clarification than providing a solution. Now that you have 50 reputation points you can comment on any post.

Comment: @nhinkle you mean "Michał Półrolniczak", not me ;)

Comment: @magicandre1981 oops ;)